# Is Gana Kuta authentic as per texts?

Tags: scripture, krishna, rama, astrology

[Gana Kuta](http://www.saravali.de/articles/koota_gana.html) has three classifications:

- deva
- manushya
- rakshasa

Which Hindu text says about it and what does it imply?

Suppose a human belongs to deva gana, is he superior to the other two ganas?

What are the gana of Gods like Rama and Krishna?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some [basic things](http://www.astrojyoti.com/lesson2.htm) about Rasis and Nakshtras are to be understood first:

> First the zodiac was divided into 12 main rasis, to study the effects
>   of the planets placed there. Then the ancient seers added another sub
>   divisional system of breaking down the zodiac into 27 Nakshatras or
>   star constellations. Each nakshatra has a span of 13 degrees and 20
>   minutes. After that each nakshatra was further subdivided into 4
>   Padas, or quarters, of 3 degrees and 20 minutes. Hence the first
>   zodiac sign Aries, which has 30 degrees, contains the entire 4 padas
>   (13:20′) of the 1st star constellation Ashwini, the entire 4 padas
>   (13:20′) of the 2nd star constellation Bharani and the 1st pada
>   (3:20′) of the third star constellation Krittika. **So each rasi
>   contains total 9 padas**. These nakshatras belong to three main groups:
>   Deva or divine, Manusha or human and Rakshasa or Demonic.

**And,yes Gana Koota is authentic** and The [Brihat Parashara Hora Shastra](http://shenjiva.com/Vedic/BrihatParasaraHora.pdf) text mentions about the 3 Ganasa viz:Deva ,Manushya and Rakshasa.

In Chapter 6 (titled "Sixteen divisions of Rasis")the concept is described as follows:

> O Maharishi Parasar, I have known from you about the Grahas, Rashis
>   and their descriptions. I desire to know the details of various
>   divisions of a Rashi, will you please narrate. 2-4. Names of the 16
>   Vargas. Lord Brahma has described 16 kinds of Vargas (Divisions) for
>   each Rashi. Listen to those. The names are Rashi, Hora, Dreshkan,
>   Chaturthans, Saptans, Navans, Dashans, Dvadashans, Shodashans,
>   Vimshans, Chaturvimshans, Saptavimshans, Trimshans, Khavedans,
>   Akshavedans and Shashtians.....
>
> The Navans calculation are for a Movable Rashi from there itself, for
>   a Fixed Rashi from the 9th thereof and for a Dual Rashi from the 5th
>   thereof. **They go by designations Deva (divine), Manushya (human) and
>   Rakshasa (devilish) in a successive and repetitive order for a Movable
>   Rashi. (Manushya, Rakshasa and Deva are the order for a Fixed Rashi,
>   while Rakshasa, Manushya and Deva are a Dual Rashi’s order)**

Calculating like the way mentioned above, we arrive at the following classification of 27 Nakshtras as per their Ganas:

**Deva Gana Nakshatras**:Aswini, Mrigasira, Punarvasu, Pushya, Hasta, Swati, Anuradha, Shravana, Revati.

**Manushya Gana Nakshtras**:Bharani, Rohini, Ardra, Purvaphalguni, Uttaraphalguni, Purvashada, Uttarashada, Purvabhadrapada, Uttarabhadrapada.

**Rakshasa Gana Nakshatras**:Krittika, Aslesha, Magha, Chitra, Visakha, Jyesta, Moola, Dhanista, Satabhisha.

Lord Rama's nakshtra is [Punarvasu](http://www.astrojyoti.com/punarvasu.htm) ,so Deva Gana & Lord Krishna's nakshatra is [Rohini](http://www.astrojyoti.com/rohini.htm),so Manushya Gana.

*Suppose a human belongs to deva gana, is he supreme than other two ganas and so on?*

Generally speaking,one  belonging to Deva Gana will be more of a Sattvik nature person,Manushya Gana of Rajasik  and Raksasha Gana of Tamasik nature.But in calculating the nature of person as a whole "Nakshtra Gana" is not the only deciding factor.The 5 limbs or "Panchangas" of a birth consist of Nakshatra,Tithi,Vara,Yoga &Karanam.And each of these 5 limbs has their equal contribution in shaping a personality.